# Convert a pth pytorch file to an onnx model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, onnx

I'm trying to convert a PyTorch model(pth file containing weights) to an onnx file then to a TensorFlow model since I work on TensorFlow. to then fine-tune it.
This is my attempt so far. I keep however getting errors.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLQpJ.png)
I think the problem is that the weights are for a vision transformer. But I haven't figure out what type of model to use to convert it. I'm assuming a CRNN but if there is an easier way I would love to know.
PS: I did load the pth file to my drive. the path is correct

```
from torch.autograd import Variable

import torch.onnx
import torchvision
import torch
import onnx
import torch.nn as nn

dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)
file_path='/content/drive/MyDrive/VitSTR/vitstr_base_patch16_224_aug.pth'

model = torchvision.models.vgg16()

model.load_state_dict(torch.load(file_path))

model.eval()

torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "vitstr.onnx")
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting Roua? Please add information so that people can help you, otherwise it is likely that your question will be closed.

Comment: Add the whole error stack to your description.

Comment: Are you trying to load a `Vision Transformer` model's weights and biases into a `VGG16` model ?

Comment: I have updated the description. Thank you very much I hope it is clear now

Comment: @Kishore is probably correct: it does not make sense to load the parameters of a vision transformer into a newly initialized VGG model. The error message you are seeing is telling you that the parameter names are different.

Comment: How did you obtain this model checkpoint: `vitstr_base_patch16_224_aug.pth`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.
I used the same architecture as the one in the model and it worked.